# python convert multiple lists to row for certain lists

Tags: python, dataframe, melt

I have the following dataframe :

```
network   date       count2    count3  user2     user3 
3         20170721   [6, 7]    [1,3]   [57,88]   [47,58] 
4         20170721   [6]       []      [12]      []
43        20170721   []        [7,2]   []        [57,62]
```

and I would like to split the list per row but count and user must correspond :

```
network   date       count2   count3  user2    user3 
3         20170727   6       Nan      57       Nan
3         20170727   7       Nan      88       Nan
3         20170727   Nan     1        Nan      47
3         20170727   Nan     3        Nan      58
4         20170727   6       Nan      12       Nan
43        20170727   Nan     7        Nan      57
43        20170727   Nan     2        Nan      62
```

How can I do it in a fast way ? The user list is in reality really long (more than 50k entry).
Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show me what the results are when you convert the dataframe into an array using .asarray?

Comment: Show us what you have done, even it's slow

Comment: What do you mean by "count and user must correspond"? You don't list any examples of corresponding count and user values except `Nan`.

What is your expected outcome? What exactly does "split the list per row" mean? What happens to each row of data???

Comment: I have tried this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793622/pandas-dataframe-expand-rows-with-lists-to-multiple-row-with-desired-indexing-f for user 2 then user3 and concat the dataframe but it is not optimal

Comment: @AMagoon. I think the example shows what is to be done pretty clearly.

Comment: @eleanor. Great. That fixes everything. Why are you even asking a question then?

Comment: Use this as well: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: Because groupby then concat  is taking a lots a time and I want to be the fastest possible

Comment: Why do you need it to be so fast? Python is python.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ya I see it now. What really threw me off was "count and user must **correspond**", as in match.

Comment: @AMagoon. Me too. I think the relatively poor prose can be forgiven given that expected results are provided. What can not be forgiven is the lack of any attempt to solve the problem: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256328/2988730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this and achieve the result you are looking for without all the extra NaN.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'network':[3,4,43],'date':['20170721']*3,
                   'count2':[[6,7],[6],[]],
                   'count3':[[1,3],[],[7,2]],
                   'user2':[[57,88],[12],[]],
                   'user3':[[47,58],[],[57,62]]})

df = df.set_index(['network','date'])

(df.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist(),index=x.index)
                      .stack()
                      .rename(x.name))
   .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   network      date  level_2  level_0  count2  count3  user2  user3
0        3  20170721        0      0.0     6.0     1.0   57.0   47.0
1        3  20170721        1      NaN     7.0     3.0   88.0   58.0
2        4  20170721        0      1.0     6.0     NaN   12.0    NaN
3       43  20170721        0      2.0     NaN     7.0    NaN   57.0
4       43  20170721        1      NaN     NaN     2.0    NaN   62.0
```