# How to convert a string contain tuple of integers to tuple with integer elements

Tags: python, string, list, integer, tuples

I have this string:

```
x="(255,255,233...)"
```

And I want to convert it to tuple. However without any string objects. 
But I got something like this :

```
x=("255","233")
```

I tried to use a for loop and `isdigit()` and `tuple()`, 
but it didn't give me what I want.

I want it to be tuple with integer elements without  "," or "()" in the tuple.

Comment: You can use `eval()` but this can be dangerous if you do not trust the input..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [covert a string which is a list into a proper list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735859/covert-a-string-which-is-a-list-into-a-proper-list-python)

Comment: @MM Where did you get that input from? In any case, you’ve show that you managed to get a tuple of strings, so the only real question left here (aside from the ones about this situation as a whole) is how to parse a bunch of strings in a tuple to ints.

Comment: Hello, can I ask why you've deleted the bit about Pygame? It's quite relevant to the problem you're trying to solve. Saving and loading integers to/from a file is a much easier, faster, and robuster problem than parsing tuples from a file.

Comment: hi  – Izaak van Dongen, i deleted it because the problem solved by using Marcos answer. I just thought there is no need for the edit.  if you asked why I saved it in the file with tuple string form , that was because of the attribute: surface.get_at((x,y)) , which save the color of the pixels like this way, unfortunately:(

Comment: Are you sure there's no way you can change the format of the file you're saving to? If you have access to tuples you can do something [like this](https://gist.github.com/goedel-gang/a002e2a8aa5f6172f96b59574c5ad91b). I'm just worried that you've fallen prey to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) `:)`. "Data serialisation" is a well-covered topic, and you have all sorts of other tools like pickle or JSON at your disposal.

Comment: I agree with @IzaakvanDongen, actually, this might very well be a case of the XY problem.

Comment: Oh yes that works too.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can safely use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on a string like this:

```
import ast

x="(255,255,233)"

ast.literal_eval(x)
# (255, 255, 233)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this:

```py
x = "(255,255,233...)"
tuples = tuple(int(number) for number in x.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('...', '').split(','))
print(tuples)

>>> (255, 255, 233)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ast library for this case:

```
import ast

x = "(255,255,233...)"

data = ast.literal_eval(x.replace(".",""))

print(type(data))

print(type(data[0]))

print(data)
```

`literal_eval()` is a safer option than using `eval()`.

Only caveat is the solution assumes the presence of the periods **"."** in the input strings. You have to know the variations you would encounter  in the input data.